# Unable to connect to mongodb replicaset Google Compute Engine

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a 3 node replicaSet for mongodb on google compute engine, for the testing purpose i have added `0.0.0.0/0` for the firewall rule and I'm able to connect to individual node from anywhere and all the instances work without any issue! but the problem is when i tried to connect to the replicaset, using the following command

```
mongo "mongodb://username:password@public-ip-1:27017,public-ip-2:27017,public-ip-3:27017/production?replicaSet=rs0"
```

1. When I'm trying this code another instance on the same project, it work's without any issue
2. When I try from a different project instance or my local instance, it is throwing error as follow

> 2020-08-22T14:36:40.579+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("mongodb-1-servers-vm-0") failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> 2020-08-22T14:36:40.582+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("mongodb-1-servers-vm-1") failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> 2020-08-22T14:36:40.582+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Unable to reach primary for set rs0

and from these instance I'm able to connect to individual nodes separately, as

```
mongo "mongodb://username:passsword@public-ip-1:27017/production"
mongo "mongodb://username:passsword@public-ip-2:27017/production"
mongo "mongodb://username:passsword@public-ip-3:27017/production"
```

What could be the problem ?

The second question is, on the firewall these is an option to add app engine service account? so if i disable the `0.0.0.0/0` public access and add this rule, can i connect from my app engine to these instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to a replica set, the client uses a server discovery process.  The basic steps are:

1. connect to the first host in the connection string

   - if that fails try the second
2. once a connection is established, run commands such `isMaster` to:

   - discover the names of all of the replica set members
   - discover which node is currently primary
3. close the initial connection
4. connect to every member of the replica set using the hostname and port discovered in step 2

What this means is that the host name returned from `rs.conf()` or `rs.status()` must be resolvable by every client that you want to be able to directly connect to the replica set.

From the error message, it looks like the nodes were added to the replica set using short names.  If you add the short name for each node to the hosts file on the machine you are connection from, it should work.

Alternately, rebuild the replica set using publicly resolvable hostnames in the `rs.initiate` and `rs.add` commands.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I can see these connection string in my /etc/hosts Can you give me any thought process or solution for my second query ? How to securely connect to the same replicaset from an app engine

Comment: The app engine will need to resolve these names, so either add them to the hosts file where the app engine is running, or rebuild the replica set using hostnames the app engine can resolve.

Comment: is it possible for you to share a document / article which specifies how to pass hosts on app engine ? Please

Comment: Is it better to connect over the public ip or the private ip ? for the replication configuration ? which one is preferred

Comment: So if i create the replica with private ip and if i try to connect to the replica using the private ip? will i get the same error ?

Comment: The specific error you are getting is `getaddrinfo("mongodb-1-servers-vm-0") failed`, so you either need to make it resolve `mongodb-1-servers-vm-0` to an IP address, or change the hostname contained in the `rs.conf()` to something that it can resolve

Comment: Jeo, I understood that, and i really thank you for that, but my doubt is, if i change the connection on rs.conf() to local ip, then will i get the same error error ? because if im trying to connect from outside the network, as you said if it fetches the connection prams and try to connect to each host, then all connection string will be local address right ?  then it wont be possible right ?

Comment: That is correct, using an IP address that is not reachable/routeable on the public network will cause the same problem as using a hostname that is not resolvable from the public network.