# MongoDB: Replica set where servers communicate on internal network

Tags: mongodb

I have a Replica Set deployment where my servers are on an internal network and they are visible on that network as:

- mongodata0:27017
- mongodata1:27017
- mongodata2:27017

All three servers are visible over the internet (single load balancer, NAT-ed ports) as:

- mymongoserver.com:27017
- mymongoserver.com:27018
- mymongoserver.com:27019

Now with this setup in mind, connecting from the internal network is easy, the conn string goes like "mongodata1:27017,mongodata2:27017,mongodata3:27017".
However, connecting from the internet is impossible, because I need to use the conn string "mymongoserver.com:27017,mymongoserver.com:27018,mymongoserver.com:27019", and the mongo client gives me an error that says:

> "FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not find host matching read
> preference { mode: "nearest" } for set myReplSet"

Which to me sounds like Mongo doesn't like the fact that the URI of each individual member as seen by the other members, is different from the URI supplied by the mongo client.
I can always connect to each one of the members individually, but not to the whole replica set as such.

Now I could probably configure the replica set members to see each other with their external IPs, thus I can connect to the replica set over the internet, but I will then lose the ability to connect from the internal network.
This does seem like a very common deployment scenario and one might expect it has a very standard solution (the only quirky thing is the NAT-ed ports, but I doubt it makes any difference). However, I've been fruitlessly raking the internet for a solution or a best practice in that regard for quite some time now.

The only solution I came up with thus far is accessing the servers behind an SSL tunnel, so that I can address them as mongodata0,... and have the mongodata0, mongodata1 and mongodata2 host names bound to localhost in my /etc/hosts, but that feels rather clunky and still requires that the ports of the members are different in the internal network.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63534722/2282634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up split horizon DNS. Use the host names that are accessible from external hosts, but from the nodes themselves resolve them using internal IPs.

This is easiest to do using the hosts file but you can also run a local DNS server.

Comment: Split horizon DNS sounds like the solution, although it sounds somewhat hacky. I found [this part of the mongo spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#clients-use-the-hostnames-listed-in-the-replica-set-config-not-the-seed-list) which says "replica set members must be reachable from the client by the hostnames listed in the replica set config.". This basically means that DNS shenanigans are the only way to achieve this inter-network replica set connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a network specialist, but I would assume there are solutions available.

From application point of view I have two proposals.

1. Connect to single host, e.g. `mymongoserver.com:27017`. This might be the PRIMARY member or a SECONDARY. Then [open a new connection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo/) to the replica set:

   ```
   db = Mongo("mongodb://user/password@mongodata1:27017,mongodata2:27017,mongodata3:27017/replicaSet=replSet&authSource=admin").getDB("admin")
   ```

   However, your client driver may not support the `Mongo()` method.
2. Deploy a [Sharded Cluste](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)r. Make the `mongos` host accessible from internet, or even better setup 2 `mongos` hosts, one internal and one public.

Comment: Having limited experience with sharded clusters, I'm wondering if the same issue stands when using a mongos router. If the router actually acts as "reverse proxy with benefits", then I can happilly have my mongo instances not vivible from outside, because mongos will handle and route all the connections. However, if the router is only the handshake device, which then delegates your connection to the approipriate mongod instance, then you still need to see those mongod instances from outside, with the same names as from the internal network. Have you any idea which is the case with mongos?

Comment: The mongos config has `sharding.configDB` - there you would need to put the internal host names of the config servers. It must act as "reverse proxy with benefits", because as shown in the documentation you optionally use ClientSideFieldLevelEncryptionOptions, so it cannot be only a handshake device.

Comment: Consider a local sharded cluster, there is no need to open your firewall from your local PC to Config or Shard server. All you need is a connection to the mongos host. [Traffic to and from mongos Instances](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/#traffic-to-and-from-mongos-instances)
*mongos instances provide query routing for sharded clusters. Clients connect to mongos instances, which behave from the client's perspective as mongod instances. In turn, the mongos connects to all mongod instances that are components of the sharded cluster.* So, should work.

Comment: From what I read up to now, I tend to agree this should work. It is a usable and perhaps more elegant solution, even though it doesn't answer the initial question.

Comment: mongoses do not advertise their own addresses and the driver doesn't connect to the internal mongos addresses like it would to the RS nodes. A sharded cluster can have mongoses on different networks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this 3 to your replica set?

```
rs.add('mymongoserver.com:27017')
rs.add('mymongoserver.com:27018')
rs.add('mymongoserver.com:27019')
```

After that your rs.conf() will consist of 6 members, 3 internal and 3 domain name. Although the 3 domain name members will have a state of unhealthy. You may be able to connect to it over the internet.

I'm still checking on how this works but I think having the 3 domain names as members in the replicaset acted as proxy (dont quote me on this, just my theory as I cant see any doc for this) for it to connect to the PRIMARY which has the internal IP as hostname.